# Why is replace only working in some occasions?

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing and merging some Excel files for a project, and I realized my merged dataframe is missing 2 lines. After analyzing what was happening, I came to the conclusion that the error is associated with the following code line:

```
energy['Country'] = (energy['Country'].replace({'China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region': 'Hong Kong',
                                                'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland': 'United Kingdom',
                                                'Republic of Korea': 'South Korea',
                                                'United States of America': 'United States'}))
```

Now, the weird part is that, if I run the file which has my whole code and check the column 'Country' in the dataframe `energy`, I see that the replacements intended above were not made and, therefore, when merging all dataframes, 'United States', for example, is not in the inner joint (because in this dataframe it is recognized as 'United States of America' whereas in others it is only 'United States').

If I copy paste the entire code into the console, it will also not work as intended.

However, if I run the whole code, then copy paste the code above to the console and then copy paste the rest of the code, it will work, with the correct names for the countries mentioned above.

Any ideas why this is happening? Does it have to do with indentation?

Comment: I experienced similar things in two occasions: 1. leading and trailing white spaces, 2. `energy` is a slice of a bigger data frame.

Comment: @Quang Hoang The leading and trailing white spaces I've already checked, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Energy is indeed a slice of a bigger dataframe, as I have, at a certain point: `energy = energy.iloc[:, 2:]`

But what's the implication here? I tried doing `energy = energy[[name of columns that I want]]` and it solved the problem, but why?